# Get files from directories [including subdirectories] C#

Tags: c#, file, sorting, directory, subdirectory

For every directory (including subdirectories) I want to take the files in them and put them in a list.

I know there is something like:

```
string[] files;
files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The thing is I want to stop after every directory (or subdirectory) and sort the files in it in some way. The option above simply takes all the files altogether.

Comment: why don't you sort it after getting all? and what kind of sort you mean?

Comment: You could group your complete list, by the directory path. Like this ``files.GroupBy(x => Path.GetDirectoryName(x));`` and than do what ever you want with those groups

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Natural Sort the files for EACH directory, not altogether.

Comment: Why not sorting all files? You'll get the full path with `GetFiles` so they are sorted including the folder of the file.

Comment: XY Problem. From what we see, sorting after each folder is no different than sorting after getting all, so what's the reason for the need to sort after each folder perhaps that's the real issue?

Comment: @gilliduck exactly the reason why I said - ``and than do what ever you want with those groups`` in my comment, it sure makes no sense if its only about sorting

Comment: You likely want to use Directory.EnumerateFiles rather than GetFiles. It returns an IEnumerable rather than an Array. Thus you won't just receive all of the data right at the end, it will 'stream' out. And you can do any LINQ operations on it that you want to.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to stop after every directory (or subdirectory) and sort the files in it in some way.

If I understand what you want, You need something like this:

```
public class DirectoryFiles
{
    public DirectoryFiles(string currentDir)
    {
        CurrentDir = currentDir;
        Files = Directory.GetFiles(currentDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            .OrderBy(o=> o);
        Directories = Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir)
            .Select(c => new DirectoryFiles(c))
            .OrderBy(o=> o.CurrentDir);
    }

    public string CurrentDir { get; private set; }

    //// list of files in this directory
    public IEnumerable<string> Files { get; private set; }

    //// list of directories in this directory
    public IEnumerable<DirectoryFiles> Directories { get; private set; }
}
```

Useage:

```
var d = new DirectoryFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
string[] fols = files.GroupBy(f => Path.GetDirectoryName(f)).ToArray();
for(int i=0;i<fols.Length;i++){
     //You have each folders files in fols[i] nd you can sort it
}
```

Comment: `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<Grouping<string, string>>`. You have to either call `ToList` or use a `foreach` loop

Comment: I always and always forget it. well unlike visual studio You don't get to know your error here ;)

Comment: You can always use `C# interactive` or an online compiler like [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to check code before you post

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your files :

First , by name so that all files from a directory are right next to each other.

Second, by your other parameter (suppose file size)

Use it like this :

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                             .OrderBy(f => new FileInfo(f).FileName).ThenBy(f => new FileInfo(f).Length);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `.OrderBy(f => f.FileName)` f in here is a string and does not contain `FileName` property